# How to move copyright to top in maps v2 for android?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2, copyright-display

According to [attribution guidelines of google maps](http://www.google.com/permissions/geoguidelines/attr-guide.html) I have to show the copyright of Google and the map providers when showing a map in my android application. The copyright is usually displayed at the bottom of the mapview.
The problem with that is that I have a circular widget at the bottom of my app that hides some of the copyright notice.
This is why I want to move the copyright to the top of the mapview using

> [GoogleMap.setPadding(0, 0, 0, *mapViewHeight - copyRightFontHeight*)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map?hl=de#map_padding).

The changes that come with *setPadding* are:

> - Camera movements via API calls or button presses (e.g., compass, my location, zoom buttons) will be relative to the padded region.
> - getCameraPosition() will return the center of the padded region.
> - Projection.getVisibleRegion() will return the padded region.
> - UI controls will be offset from the edge of the container by the specified number of pixels.

But I want the standard behaviour for all of these functions (the ones that you get without padding)!

So either: How can I only move the copyright, without altering the behaviour of the mentioned functions?
Or: How do I make these functions work normally, out of the borders of the padding?

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need to use the text provided on the imagery?
>
> The automatically generated Google logo and data provider attribution
>   may only be removed or obstructed if reintroduced in a visible form
>   elsewhere within the Content (e.g. photo caption below a Google Earth
>   still). In other words, your text must be as visible as it would have
>   been if you had used the default text that we provide.

Looks like you are allowed to put the same text in yourself as long as it is just as visible.  I would suggest using negative margins to lower the default text out of view and then use a TextView to display the copyright text.